# Hapi-Joi validate payload which can be a Array of objects or just simple Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I have a post call which can take the payload as a single `JS` object as well as array of objects to save it to the db. How to write a schema to validate against such payload ?

JS object

```
{
  label: 'label',
  key: 'key',
  help_text: 'text'
}
```

Or

```
[
{
  label: 'label1',
  key: 'key1',
  help_text:'text1'
 },
 {
  label: 'label2',
  key: 'key2',
  help_text:'text2'
 }
 ]
```

Comment: First parse it from JSON. `JSON.parse(jsObj)`; Than check if it is an array or object. Be carefull, an array is an object as well. For an array you can use the Prototype: `Array.isArray(arr)`; For an object you can use this: `value !== null && (typeof value === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(value)) === 'object';`

Comment: Thanks @DominikNoll i have that logic already in my handler i am segregating all the validation part in separate files and than validating when defining routes inside config object.

Comment: Mh, than i dont get your question... You want to know how you name the routes ? Or you want to know how to handle the JS-Object in a function ? @kailash yogeshwar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [Joi.alternatives()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.1.0/API.md#alternatives). Here is a working example:

```
const joi = require('joi');

var objectSchema = joi.object().keys({
    label: joi.string().required(),
    key: joi.string().required(),
    help_text: joi.string().required()
}).unknown(false);

var arraySchema = joi.array().items(objectSchema);

var altSchema = joi.alternatives().try(objectSchema, arraySchema);

var objTest = {label: 'cuthbert', key: 'something', help_text: 'helping!'};

var arrTest = [
    objTest
];

var failingArrTest = [
    {
        unknownProperty: 'Jake'
    }
];

var result = joi.validate(objTest, altSchema);

var resultArrTest = joi.validate(arrTest, altSchema);

var resultFailingArrTest = joi.validate(failingArrTest, altSchema);

console.log(result);

console.log(resultArrTest);

console.log(resultFailingArrTest);
```

Comment: i will test that first